# $777^{401} \pmod {1000}$ is?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

here's an arithmetic question : find the last $3$ digits of $777^{401}$. I don't know where to start. The chinese remainder theorem gives a double congruence modulo $8$ and $125$ but I don't think this is really helping, there might be a simpler way. Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good place to start, but not necessary the way the problem is given.

Hint 1:

> What theorems do you know that can help reduce exponents in a congruence? (If you don't know the answer look at Hint 2)

Hint 2:
[this theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Euler%27s_theorem) (click after looking at hint 1)

Solution:

> Consider $\varphi(8)$ and $\varphi(125)$. $\varphi(8)=4 | 400$, and $\varphi(125)=100 | 400$, and since $\varphi$ is multiplicative $\varphi(1000)=400 | 400$. So by Euler's theorem, if 777 is relatively prime to 1000 (which it is), $777^{401}= 777^{400}\cdot 777 \equiv 777 \pmod{1000}$. In fact, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, $777^{100}\equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$ since $100$ is the least common multiple of $4$ and $100$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $777\equiv 1 \pmod{2^3}$ and $777\equiv 27\pmod{5^3}$. Moreover  $\varphi(5^3)=4\cdot 5^2$ and $401 \equiv 1\pmod{100}$ therefore we have
$777^{401}\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ and $777^{401} \equiv 27\pmod{125}$.

Then by CRT the solution exists and it is unique modulo $1000$, i.e.
$$
777^{401}\equiv 777 \pmod{1000}.
$$

Comment: Don't you already know that the unique solution is 777 by the first sentence?

Comment: Your CRT calculation of $152$ is not equivalent to $1$ modulo $8$

Comment: Oh right, I had I mistake computing the last result, I fix it in a moment.

Comment: jgon, you are right xd

Answer (score 2):

$$777=7\times 3\times 37~\textrm{and}~1000=5^3\times 2^3\implies \gcd(777,1000)=1$$

Hence, we use Euler's theorem. We have, $$\phi(1000)=\phi(5^3\times 2^3)=1000\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)=400$$

Now, according to Euler's theorem, we have,

$$777^{\phi(1000)}\equiv 1\pmod{1000}\implies 777^{400}\equiv 1\pmod{1000}$$

$$\implies 777^{401}=777^{401~\bmod~400}\equiv 777^1\equiv 777\pmod{1000}$$

Comment: Hence, the last three digits are obviously $777$.

Answer (score 1):

Use Euler's theorem: As $\phi(1000)= \phi(125)\times \phi(8)= 400$ we have  $777^{400}\equiv1$ mod $1000$, as $\gcd(777,1000)=1$. So the answer is $777^{401}\equiv777$ mod $1000$.